# Does CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage() run asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Should I register a callback to handle the canvas blob object or does the **CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage()** blocking javascript execution until **drawImage()** is completed?

Comment: Yes it runs synchronously, but it's unclear what you are talking about with "blob object"

Comment: After drawImage() execution I want to call **canvas.toBlob()** method and I'd like to be sure that the new image is drawn successfully. @Kaiido 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob

Answer (score 3):

Yes *CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage* does run synchronously, but maybe not in the way you want...

If the sourceImage provided has not finished to *fetch* its resource (in case of HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement) then, it will not wait for this.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "https://slowserv.er/bigImage.png";
ctx.drawImage(img, x, y); // here it won't wait for the image to be fetched
```

But if the image has been completely fetched, and its metadata has been parsed but the image data has not yet been *decoded*, then `drawImage` will wait for it to be decoded. You can see a demo of this by running [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39543762/3702797) from Firefox.
<sub>This behavior seems to be catch-able only in Firefox, since Chrome will actually wait for the image to be decoded before firing the *onload* event.</sub>

So to answer your question, if the sourceImage is in a loaded status (e.g `img.naturalWidth !== 0` for `<img>`), then yes, you can be sure that drawImage will get executed before the next line of code is.

```
if(img.naturalWidth !==0) { // here we are sure our image is loaded
  ctx.drawImage(img, x, y); // and here we are sure it has been drawn on the canvas
  // even though toBlob is itself async
  // this will pick the canvas has it is now
  ctx.canvas.toBlob(onblobgenerated, options);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Kaiido for your valuable advice!

My canvas image source is a HTMLVideoElement connected to a MediaStream (web camera), so I should be sure that the image is loaded before calling getImage

Comment: Yes, same as with an HTMLImageElement.naturalWidth, you can check HTMLVideoElement.videoWidth to be sure it has something to be drawn. Or even simply `video.onloadedmetadata` or `oncanplay` if it has its autoplay set to true, or even `video.play().then(drawAndExport)` since I guess you are targeting new browsers.

Comment: I'll go with video.play().then(drawAndExport) Promise API solution, thanks again!