# How can I asynchronously render images using HTML canvas (and vue.js)?

Tags: html, vue.js, asynchronous, html5-canvas

I have a program that keeps track of a number.  If you get above your goal number, you visit a page that shows how much extra you have stored up.  On that page is a gumball machine, and depending on the number of excess you have stored up, a certain number of gumballs appear in side the machine.  Everything works fine, but about 1 out of every 3 page loads, the gumballs appear first, and then the machine appears, covering all of the gumball images first.

This is being done through vue.js  Here is the code I have:

```
created () {
    this.$http.get('/gumballs/' + this.$auth.user().id).then(res => {)
      this.createCanvas()
    })
  }

*******

    createCanvas () {
      // general canvas properties...
      // gumball machine properties
      this.createGumbllMachine(canvas.width, ctx, (err, succ) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
        } else if (succ) {
          this.createGumballs(canvas.width, ctx)
        }
      })
    }

**********

    createGumballMachine (width, ctx, cb) {
      const imgObj = document.createElement('img')
      imgObj.src = machineImg
      imgObj.onload = () => {
        ctx.drawImage(imgObj, (width / 2) - 350, 100)
      }
      return cb(null, 'ok')
    }
```

I have tried to use a callback function as the last argument in `createGumballMachine()` so that the machine is drawn first and then the gumballs are drawn afterwards, but this doesn't work.

I also tried using `async` and `await` but I coudn't get the image to render at all that way.  Something was happening where vue could never get past the `created` portion of it's lifecycle.

I have tried reading about this on other SO questions, but I can't figure it out.  I know it has something to do the way `ctx.dtawImage()` works, but I'm stuck.

Any help is appreciated.  If you need to see the code for `createGumballs()` let me know, but I don't see how that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Linking a relevant answer which also explains the inconsistent behavior. Essentially, you can use naturalWidth to ensure that the gumball machine has loaded.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51023755/4409088

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up using an array where the gumball machine is the first and all the rest are the gumballs.  They are drawn from the array in order, so that fixed it.